# My SQL Query is working but giving me the records multiple times

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database : one is `Pages` and the other one is `Liked`. Both tables have a `user_id` column. In `Pages` table, the `user_id` column is the `id` of `user` who has created the `page`.While in the `Liked` column the `user_id` column is the `user` who liked the page. I want to fetch the records of pages that has been not liked or created by a particular user `(say user_id=2)`
Here is my query it is working fine but not giving me the output which i want.

```
SELECT *
FROM page p
JOIN liked l ON l.pg_id=p.pg_id
WHERE p.u_id!=2
  AND l.u_id!=2;
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: I want to show the pages that are not liked by the user and which is not created by himself

Comment: yes michael check my query n tell what i have done wrong

Comment: You need to use a full outer join but mysql doesn't suppor them so two lefts and a union will have to do...

Comment: @xQbert can you make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NOT EXISTS clause to check for pages that are not owned or liked by the user:

```
SELECT *
FROM page p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM liked l WHERE l.u_id = 2 AND p.pg_id = l.pg_id)
AND p.u_id != 2
```

Comment: @Zeeshan Can you be more specific is there any error?

Comment: giving me syntax error

can you explain me that we can use two where clauses in a single query and in subquery after where clause there is no AND, OR operator after this (l.u_id = 2)

Comment: @Zeeshan That was a typo in my query which I've fixed. Copying the error would have helped me spot it.

Comment: The query is not working can u give me its alternative?

Comment: @Zeeshan I cannot help if you wont tell me how it isn't working and the specific error if there is one.

Comment: this is the query u tell and below is th error

SELECT * FROM page p WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM liked l WHERE l.u_id =2 AND p.pg_id=l.pg_id) WHERE p.u_id!=2;

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p.u_id!=2' at line 2

Comment: @Zeeshan Another typo. The last WHERE should be AND.